# jQuery Draggable element that follows a line

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I got a div element that contains an image, and another div that is a drop zone for the element div.

At the moment i can take the draggable div and drag it anywhere i want (in any direction i mean).

I want to connect these two divs with an invisible line and then make it so the image div could only be draggable on this line.

These two divs are not on same position so using the draggable axis function doesn't work for me here.

As i was doing some research, to draw a line between the two elements i think jsplumb plugin would do that job, but would it be possible to 'snap' the image element on this line? Maybe there are other options?

jsfiddle.net/v34c6/ - simple jsfiddle that has 2 squares, draggable element can move in any  dirrection, i want restrict its movements with an insisible line that is connected from draggable object to droppable object.

Comment: Can you provide some code, which we could experiment on?

Comment: Eddited code with simple jsfiddle that has 2 squares, one is draggable other is droppable. Draggable can move in any dirrection, i want its movement restricted by an invisible line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12899802/1414562

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to drag a shape along a given path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406021/how-to-drag-a-shape-along-a-given-path)