# Snap.svg determine drag distance along a path

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael, snap.svg

As referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406021/how-to-drag-a-shape-along-a-given-path) and updated for use with Snap.svg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773144/snap-svg-drag-group-along-path), I'd like to better understand how the provided gradSearch function actually works (it's a bit over my head), and whether there are any good alternatives to this approach?

```
gradSearch = function (l0, pt) {
    l0 = l0 + totLen;
    var l1 = l0,
        dist0 = dist(path.getPointAtLength(l0 % totLen), pt),
        dist1,
        searchDir;

    if (dist(path.getPointAtLength((l0 - searchDl) % totLen), pt) > 
       dist(path.getPointAtLength((l0 + searchDl) % totLen), pt)) {
        searchDir = searchDl;
    } else {
        searchDir = -searchDl;
    }

    l1 += searchDir;
    dist1 = dist(path.getPointAtLength(l1 % totLen), pt);
    while (dist1 < dist0) {
        dist0 = dist1;
        l1 += searchDir;
        dist1 = dist(path.getPointAtLength(l1 % totLen), pt);
    }
    l1 -= searchDir;
    return (l1 % totLen);
}
```

Comment: Yes.. this is something, I am also looking for. The function works well for any given path in SVG. I also want to reuse it, but interpreting the same is very difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Took me a while to understand the code, but this is how I understand it to be working (trying to keep the explanation simplified):

First the position of the draggable object on the path is recorded as `l0` (Note that this is `L0`, easy to confuse with the number 10 when first looking at the code).

The distance from the new point (where mouse has dragged to) to the position on the path is recorded as `dist0`.

The `if` statement then determines which direction to drag in.  It does this by adding `searchDl` value to the path position (i.e. length along the path), and subtracting the same value and seeing which is closer to the mouse position.

Once it knows which direction to move in, it uses the `while` loop to keep adding/subtracting the position by the `searchDl` size until the distance between the point on the path and the position of the mouse is as low as it can get.

It then returns the new position on the path.

By changing `searchDir` to a larger value you can move in larger increments and it can calculate faster at the expense of precision (If I've understood the code correctly).