# Drag along path snap.svg

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, snap.svg

Hello [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406021/how-to-drag-a-shape-along-a-given-path) [with this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzic/kKLtH/) is perfect for what I need to do - drag something along a path. 
However they used Rapael - I'd like to update things and use snap.svg instead.

Replacing the reference from Raphael to Snap in this answer doesn't work - does anyone have any ideas why?

This is as far as I've got [in this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNNMJE) - I want to have a 10 point shape - the outer points of which can move a long a path to the centre.

```js
var s = Snap("#svg");
var paths = [], points = [], circles = [], lines = [], l = 0, searchDl = 1;

var dist = function (pt1, pt2) {
    var dx = pt1.x - pt2.x;
    var dy = pt1.y - pt2.y;
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
};

var gradSearch = function (l0, pt, path) {
    var totLen = path.getTotalLength();
  l0 = l0 + totLen;
    var l1 = l0,
        dist0 = dist(path.getPointAtLength(l0 % totLen), pt),
        dist1,
        searchDir;
  
  console.log(dist0);

    if (dist(path.getPointAtLength((l0 - searchDl) % totLen), pt) > 
       dist(path.getPointAtLength((l0 + searchDl) % totLen), pt)) {
        searchDir = searchDl;
    } else {
        searchDir = -searchDl;
    }

    l1 += searchDir;
    dist1 = dist(path.getPointAtLength(l1 % totLen), pt);
  console.log(dist1);
    while (dist1 < dist0) {
        dist0 = dist1;
        l1 += searchDir;
        dist1 = dist(path.getPointAtLength(l1 % totLen), pt);
    }
    l1 -= searchDir;
    console.log(l1 % totLen);
    return (l1 % totLen);
};

var startCircleToPoly = function () {
    // storing original coordinates
    this.ox = this.attr("cx");
    this.oy = this.attr("cy");
    this.attr({opacity: 1});
};

var moveCircleToPoly = function (dx, dy) {
    var tmpPt = {
        x : this.ox + dx, 
        y : this.oy + dy
    };
   var path = paths[this.data('int')];
    // move will be called with dx and dy
    l = gradSearch(l, tmpPt, path);
   //console.log(l);
    pt = path.getPointAtLength(l);
    this.attr({cx: pt.x, cy: pt.y});
};

var endCircleToPoly = function () {
    // restoring state
    this.attr({opacity: 1});
};

for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
  //polygon points
  points.push( s.select('#line' + i).attr('x2') + ' ' + s.select('#line' + i).attr('y2') ); 
  
  paths.push( s.path('M' + s.select('#line' + i).attr('x2') + ' ' + s.select('#line' + i).attr('y2') + ' L' + s.select('#line' + i).attr('x1') + ' ' + s.select('#line' + i).attr('y1')).attr({stroke: "blue"}) );
  
  lines.push(s.select('#line' + i).attr({'stroke' : ''}));
 
 //circles
 circles.push( s.circle(
   s.select('#line'+i).attr('x2'),
  s.select('#line'+i).attr('y2'),5).attr({
     fill: "red", 
     id: "circle"+i,
     style: {"cursor" : "pointer"}
   }).data({int: i-1}).drag( moveCircleToPoly, startCircleToPoly, endCircleToPoly )
 );
}

//add poly
/*var poly = s.polygon(points);
poly.attr({
    id:"poly",
    fill:"#555555"
});
*/
```

```html
<svg id="svg" version="1.1"  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="svg-content" viewBox="-10.109 -107.67 400 400">

<line id="line1" fill="none" x1="82.196" y1="-17.513" x2="107.595" y2="-95.686"/>
<line id="line2" fill="none" x1="82.196" y1="-17.513" x2="148.689" y2="-65.827"/>
<line id="line3" fill="none" x1="82.196" y1="-17.513" x2="164.391" y2="-17.513"/>
<line id="line4" fill="none" x1="82.196" y1="-17.513" x2="148.689" y2="30.801"/>
<line id="line5" fill="none" x1="82.196" y1="-17.513" x2="107.595" y2="60.66"/>
<line id="line6" fill="none" x1="82.196" y1="-17.513" x2="56.796" y2="60.66"/>
<line id="line7" fill="none" x1="82.196" y1="-17.513" x2="15.699" y2="30.801"/>
<line id="line8" fill="none" x1="82.196" y1="-17.513" x2="0" y2="-17.513"/>
<line id="line9" fill="none" x1="82.196" y1="-17.513" x2="15.699" y2="-65.827"/>
<line id="line10" fill="none" x1="82.196" y1="-17.513" x2="56.796" y2="-95.686"/>

</svg>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main problem is that some of the floats are being treated like strings in addition rather than numeric ids. I would also use the data() method in the odd place you weren't before.

So I would do things like the following to force numeracy, or you could use parseInt etc

```
var tmpPt = {
    x : +this.data("ox") + +dx,   
    y : +this.data("oy") + +dy
};
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbbmqW)

Added note: You may want to have a think about matrices and transformations as well as your drag is happening on elements that have a different screen transformation, so when you drag them, they move slightly quicker, so you may want to compensate for that.

Comment: Ace - thanks man - silly over sites from copy/pasting someone else's code.
Thanks for the heads up re matrices and transformations - no idea what it means so I'll do some googling. Any pointers welcome.

Comment: Ok, just to get the head thinking a bit. Suppose you drag your mouse 100px to the right, and suppose the element you are dragging is in a container that is scaled 50% smaller. You need to account for that difference, as a browser drag of 100 doesn't match a 1to1 relationship. As the container (svg or group for example) is scaled, the drag needs to move the inverse of that (so if scaled 0.5, you would drag 2x). For most cases its fine, it doesn't matter, its only on containers that are scaled or rotated etc.