# How to let line or path follow the shape when shape are move

Tags: jquery, d3.js, svg

I want to build an event when the mouse moves shape. SVG shape will follow the path or line moving.but I don't know how to do.
here's my code:
[JSbin](https://jsbin.com/ditomuxola/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

**EDIT**

I have two shapes, then I can build a line between the two shapes. When I tried to drag me want to follow the shape of the line can be increased or reduced. Now I can build a line between two shapes in my [code](https://jsbin.com/ditomuxola/edit?html,css,js,console,output), but I do not know when I drag a shape how the line can be increased or shorten

Comment: i think the question is not clear can you give more clarity of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Cyril sorry for not clear my question. Now i was update my question hope this is clear.

Comment: Do you want to move your shape along a predefined path while `mousedown` on the shape? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073090/drag-along-path-snap-svg

Comment: this image is i want to build. here's image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YzAAs.gif

Comment: D3 is best at manipulating and displaying data based objects. If your just wanting something like in the example then you might consider [PaperJS](http://paperjs.org/) It would be easier to reproduce your example image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this using d3 but you will need to define your data lik e this:

Then use force layout to place the nodes.
The links and nodes will be taken care off by the tick function.

```
graph = {
          "nodes": [{ 
            "x": 469,//x position of the node
            "y": 410, //y position of the node
            fixed: true//this is a fixed node
          }, {
            "x": 493,
            "y": 364,
            fixed: true
          }, {
            "x": 442,
            "y": 365,
            fixed: true
          }, {
            "x": 467,
            "y": 314,
            fixed: true
          }, ],
          "links": [{//link between nodes index 0 and index 1
            "source": 0,//this link node @ index 0
            "target": 1//this link node @ index 1
          }, {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 2
          }, {
            "source": 2,
            "target": 0
          }, {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 3
          }, {
            "source": 3,
            "target": 2
          }, ]
        }
```

For more circles add nodes to the graph object above, and update the links accordingly.

Full working code here

```js
    var width = 960,
      height = 500;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
      .size([width, height])
      .charge(-400)
      .linkDistance(40)
      .on("tick", tick);
    //making the drag listener
    var drag = force.drag()
      .on("dragstart", dragstart).on("dragend", dragend);
    //making svg
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);
    // build the arrow.
    svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
      .data(["end"]) // Different link/path types can be defined here
      .enter().append("svg:marker") // This section adds in the arrows
      .attr("id", String)
      .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
      .attr("refX", 25)
      .attr("refY", -1.5)
      .attr("markerWidth", 6)
      .attr("markerHeight", 6)
      .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
    
    var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
      node = svg.selectAll(".node");
    //data on nodes
    graph = {
      "nodes": [{
        "x": 469,
        "y": 410,
        fixed: true//this is a fixed node
      }, {
        "x": 493,
        "y": 364,
        fixed: true
      }, {
        "x": 442,
        "y": 365,
        fixed: true
      }, {
        "x": 467,
        "y": 314,
        fixed: true
      }, ],
      "links": [{//link between nodes
        "source": 0,
        "target": 1
      }, {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 2
      }, {
        "source": 2,
        "target": 0
      }, {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 3
      }, {
        "source": 3,
        "target": 2
      }, ]
    }
    //using forcelayout
    force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();
    //making lines
    link = link.data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link").attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
    //making nodes
    node = node.data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 12)

    .call(drag);



    function tick() {
      link.attr("x1", function(d) {
          return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
          return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          return d.target.y;
        });

      node.attr("cx", function(d) {
          return d.x;
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d.y;
        });
    }


    function dragstart(d) {
      d3.select(this).classed("fixed", true);
    }

    function dragend(d) {
      d3.select(this).classed("fixed", false);
    }
```

```css
  .link {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  
  .node {
    cursor: move;
    fill: #ccc;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  
  .node.fixed {
    fill: #f00;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Plunk is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TxconJkwiADcurUZisPG?p=preview)

Hope this helps!